# React Select Dropdown disable individual options not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, drop-down-menu, antd

I am fairly new to react, but I am trying to create a dropdown with ant-design with some of the individual options disabled based on certain IDs.All the ID data returns as expected, however, the disable logic (which I think should work) in the disable attribute seems to disable every option in the dropdown. Anyone know what could be going on?

```
<Select
        value={this.props.value}
        name={this.props.name}
        className={this.props.cssClass}
        disabled={this.props.disabled}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        mode="multiple"
        showSearch
        filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
        size="large"
      >
        {
          this.state.data.map(opt => (
            <Option
              disabled={this.props.multiSelect.filter(data => data.DivisionId !== opt.Id)}
              key={opt.Id}
              value={opt.Id}
            >
              {opt.Name}
            </Option>
          ))
        }
      </Select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with your code is that array `filter` method will always return `true` because empty array is parsed as `true`.

Replace filter method with `find` method.